# How to open *.xml.dist with eclipse XML editor

Tags: eclipse

I want to associate any `*.xml.dist` file with the eclipse XML editor. I tried the following:

1. Preferences: `General > Editors > File Associations`, yet it only accepts one dot here, so `*.xml.dist` can't be added (at least not for me? is there a trick?)
2. Preferences: `General > Content Types` I located `Text > XML` and added `.xml.dist` and `*.xml.dist` yet neither of them worked.

For sure, I can right click any file and tell `Open with > XML Editor` but I'd rather have this as default.

PS. The same would be for `*.ext.dist` (generic example here)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like quite an old bug (ouch!) - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168573

Wouldn't creating a mapping for `*.dist` help you?

I have also noticed that Eclipse appears to remember what was the editor used for given one file, so if the set of files you are working with is finite, it might be an useful crutch.